# how to make two different logins for users and admins

Tags: python, django

Here I m using django allauth for user management and I want to make two different logins for users and admin. Also the problem is how to save the user rating and review in the database.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the User model when user identity is admin:

```
User.is_superuser = True
```

when you login:

```
if request.user.is_superuser:
        return redirect('admin')
    else:
        return redirect('user')
```

and if you whant to to save the user rating and review you have to create the rating model and add

```
review = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: and how to import User . I m using django all auth